# How to get data from DB to editable table and then export to Excel?

Tags: javascript, html, excel, datagrid, html-table

I've been looking for a table or data grid that is editable and can get data from a MySQL database with no luck. 
I tried Slickgrid but there is not a lot of documentation out there and making it work is harder than I thought.
I've also tried using a regular HTML table with textfield in each cell to get the data from the DB. It works pretty well, specially when editing and saving back to the DB, but if I want to select the whole table and copy it to then paste it in Excel, it does not work as I can only select one textfield and not the whole table.

Is there anything out there that would do something similar and is not too complicated to implement? Preferrably javascript related!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Excel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

This is the way i do it. No idea if you have the ability to use PHP but its the easiest way.
You can make a function when pressing a button saying convert to exel, it puts the mysql result in an
excel sheet (you can edit the look) and present it as a downloadable file. 
Takes some trial/error to set up but once its set-up and you get the way of working, its very easy.

Comment: I have no expertise in PHP, but I'll give it a try